# Three.js - Wrong number of height segments

Tags: javascript, three.js

I did a simple sphere, the result is on [this link](http://93.184.46.144/test/index.html)

I don't understand why I have got 16 height segments knowing I have set into the source :

```
var segments = 32;
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, segments, segments, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.|        var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
PI * 2);
```

I get the good value for the number of width segments (32 on the animation) but not for height ones.

Anyone could see what's wrong ?

Just a last detail : where do the rainbow colors on the sphere come from ? (I mean, from which WebGL function ?)

Comment: You are using a version of three.js that is 3 years old. Update to the current version and repost if needed.

Comment: ok sorry, I think that the 32 height segments are on theta = 2*pi, what it does 16 on theta = pi , thanks